# Confirm before sort Jquery ui

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to ask the user to confirm if he really wants to sort the list here is my code

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu-pages").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var didConfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to Update the Navigation?");
            if (didConfirm == true) {
                $.post("ajax.php", {
                    type: "orderPages",
                    pages: $('#menupages').sortable('serialize')
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Yes it doesnt send the ajax script but it dont go back to its original position.

Comment: Can you provide jsfidle with your html code?

Comment: add the event listener to the confirm button instead and create a mask layer to ask for confirmation. (when click the button it only shows the confirmation dialogue with 2 buttons, confirm or cancel, when confirmed it triggers what you want to, when canceled it just closes your div), making sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `event.preventDefault()` inside the update callback to revert item to its original position.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zQDdg/)